# javascript onclick being called for wrong input, on Chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to resolve an issue in an existing application that I have inherited.

Below is a cut-down html and javascript page, which exhibits the issues I am facing.

Essentially, if you press enter in the top box ("Filter"), then the click handlers for both buttons are being triggered - but only in Chrome, not in IE (IE is working as expected).

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function verify(){
                return confirm("New Button Clicked");
            }
            
            function verifyFilter(){
                return confirm("Filter Button Clicked");
            }
        
            function swallowenter(button) {
                if(event.keyCode==13) {
                    event.keyCode=null;
                    window.document.getElementById(button).click();
                }    
                return true;
            }

            function swallowentercompletely() {
                if(event.keyCode==13) {
                    event.keyCode=null;
                }    
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onkeypress="javascript:swallowentercompletely();">
        <form id="formID" action="file.html" method="post">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">              
                    <tfoot>
                        <!-- main table footer -->
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="8" align="left">
                                Date: <input id="newDate" name="newDate" onkeypress="javascript:swallowenter('newButton');" type="text" value="" size="8" maxlength="10"/>
                                <input type="submit" value="New" name="newButton" onClick = "return verify()"  onkeypress="javascript:swallowenter('newButton');"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>                
                <tbody>
                    <!--  main table body  -->
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" onkeypress="javascript:swallowenter('filterButton');">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input id="filterText" name="filterText" type="text" value="Filter"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Filter" name="filterButton" id="filterButton" onClick = "return verifyFilter()" />
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </td>                                       
                                    </tr>                                   
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <!-- end main table body -->
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Additionally, removing the `<form/>` tags also makes it work in Chrome - so there's something in the way that's interacting that causes the issue. So, it's like the "New" button is the default button for the form; and the `swallowenter` method is there to cancel the default button click and replace it with the one that is passed in to the method -- but it's not cancelling the default button click for some reason Can anyone explain how to make this work correctly in Chrome too?

--- Update ---

I have put `alert(event.keyCode);` before and after `event.keyCode=null;`, and the keycode is showing as `13` both times - so why isn't it clearing the keycode in Chrome? This is true whether or not the `<form/>` tags are there. And even setting the keyCode to something other than null (e.g. 14) doesn't work - it still shows `13` both times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, in Chrome (and all modern browsers really), `event.keyCode` is read-only. This means you can't just override the value.

Instead, you need to use:

```js
function swallowenter(button) {
    if(event.keyCode==13) {
        event.preventDefault(); // CHANGED HERE
        window.document.getElementById(button).click();
    }    
    return true;
}
```

`event.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event behaviour from being acted on.

Additionally, in the code I posted, I needed to change the newButton to have an id instead of just a name; so the `getElementById` call can find it.

Note that if you require compatibility with Internet Explorer 7 or earlier, this method didn't exist and so the old method of setting the field to null will still work in that case.

Comment: Yes indeed, you had to prevent the default action

Comment: That is what I also figured out just now, I was about to update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main problem is that your closing `</form>` tag is out of scope from your closing `</body>` tag, with them in place you should get it working.

```html
<!-- this -->
<body onkeypress="javascript:swallowentercompletely();">
  <form id="formID" action="file.html" method="post">
    <!-- rest of html -->
  </body> 
</form>  


<!-- should become -->
<body onkeypress="javascript:swallowentercompletely();">
  <form id="formID" action="file.html" method="post">
    <!-- rest of html -->
  </form>
</body>
```

Also, you have to prevent the default action.

```js
function swallowenter(button) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.keyCode = null;
    window.document.getElementById(button).click(); 
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Having the `</form>` tag in the wrong place was an error when I posted to stackoverflow, not in the original code - and anyway that isn't causing the issue.

Comment: Your second point also doesn't fix it - when I run the code with that line commented out, and press enter in the text box, then "New Button" is clicked instead of Filter Button

Comment: So, it's like the "New" button is the default button for the form; and that method is there to cancel the default button click and replace it with the one that is passed in -- but it's not cancelling the default button click for some reason